# MCQ on using Statement for C# certification practice

Tags: c#, using-statement

Here's a question from the book: 
Programming in C#, Exam 70-483
The answer is c.

An object that is implementing IDisposable is passed to your class as an argument. Should you wrap the element in a using statement?

A. Yes, otherwise a memory leak    could happen.
B. No, you should
    call Close on the object.
C. No, you    should use a try/finally
    statement and call Dispose yourself.
D. No,    the calling method
    should use a using statement.

I am a little confused why c. In the question, by argument, do they mean that the object is passed as a type arguement to the class?

Comment: As "argument" I suppose they mean constructor parameter. I'd say (d) for methods parameters (as they seems to intend talking of try/finally) but with constructor I'd see (c) because it's easier to "see" an ownership change (from caller to your class, like with streams in System.IO).

Comment: Why would (c) ever be right? (a) would be preferrable to (c) in all cases. Here, (d) is correct. Closing as opinion-based. I guess this would be on-topic for code-review or programmers.

Comment: Regardless of how or why or when the argument is passed, _you should never destroy an instance which you did not create._  (d) is correct, (c) is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of how or why or when the argument is passed, *you should never destroy an instance which you did not create.*  (d) is correct, (c) is irrelevant.